# Delimiting square brackets and/or periods in JSP Expression Language

Tags: spring, jsp, el

I'm wondering how to access a variable placed in a model.

Let's say I have this java code:

```
model.addAttribute("variable[0].hasErrors", true);
```

I'm attempting to access this via EL. This doesn't work

```
${variable[0].hasErrors}
```

The issue is probably related to both the brackets and the period.

How can I directly access this variable to get the boolean value?

Comment: If Spring stores it in request scope, then `${requestScope['variable[0].hasErrors']}` should do it. But this is ridiculous. Just give it a sensible name which does not represent an EL variable by itself. If you have multiple of them, just collect all of them in a real array/list/map.

Comment: You're correct and I agree. I ended up going the route you suggested.

Comment: This is an existing page that is very poorly written and far too large and complex for what it is, so it would have been consistent with the to name the variable way I proposed. I've already spent a couple weeks fixing performance problems, and it would take even more time to re-work the other things that suck :-(